# Protect sequence of pages with same password for each of two groups of users

Tags: query, login, user-roles, user-registration, content-restriction

I'm currently creating a home page (learning environment) with wordpress. It should serve for an experimental study with two conditions. Based on the condition a participant will be assigned to, he or she should be redirected to one of two different page sequences. This redirection should start after page 10. After clicking through the group specific sequence of pages then, all participants should finally get redirected to shared (group independent) pages again.

So, they start with the same pages, then (I guess) there will be a login page where participants should enter one of two passwords (based on their affiliation to group 1 or 2), then they are going through their group specific pages, then they work through shared pages again.

Could someone please explain how I can realize that? I worked several times through all the forum posts here but there are only contributions about how to set multiple passwords for the same pages instead of the other way round.

Comment: This is kind of intricate... ...if you're doing this as a plugin I'd set plugin options where you can specify each of the 'passwords' and then for each password use a multi select/select2 field in the plugin options to set a list/array of pages in the sequence.  After that you'll have to write a series of conditions to check which route to send people down, work out how the pagination/steps are going to work, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion! Because you said "if I am doing it as a plugin" - is there an easier option to do it (e.g. without using a plugin)?

Comment: I meant it as “if I was building a plugin myself”... as far as I know the functionality you’re looking for, as a standalone doesn’t exist and needs to be build.  I think Learning Management plug-ins have functionality like this, but they do A LOT more. What you’re asking for is pretty intricate logic wise.

Comment: Ok I see, many thanks for that. Probably there is also a way to do it with filters but I am quite new to wordpress why I dont have the expertise yet.